# sms uri scheme not working with android hangout

Tags: javascript, html, sms

in android the body of the sms not populating with hangout app.

i have tried the codes below

```
<a href="sms:;body=My message">Send SMS</a>
<a href="sms:&body=My message">Send SMS</a>
<a href="sms:?body=My message">Send SMS</a>
```

Comment: It seems like as of this moment in time, certain Android messaging clients (notably Hangouts and Messenger) don't allow you to pre-fill the SMS body. My stock messages application, however, does pre-fill the body given the same, for example, `<a href="sms:?body=hi">` scheme.

Comment: Having the same problem. Doesn't work in Hangouts but regular SMS app works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "with hangout app", but to my understanding your problems could be:

- You are leaving out the recepient number(s), which is not supported by the standard (see [RFC 5724](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724))
- The message should be [url-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (there are tons of free services for online url-encoding some text)

Quoting the examples from RFC 5724, valid sms URIs are:

```
sms:+15105550101
sms:+15105550101,+15105550102
sms:+15105550101?body=hello%20there
```

In your case it should suffice to add the destination, url-encode the body and wrap it into an HTML `<a>` tag as you did:

```
<a href="sms:+15105550101?body=My%20message">Send SMS</a>
```

Where, of course, you should replace `+15105550101` with the number of your intended recipient.